# Browser print pop up with print option always.(not the last chosen one)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, browser

I have a usecase where I'd need the print pop up to display on load. I have done that using window.print().
By default, window.print() would show you the last decision in the browser, i.e, to print or to save as PDF.
Is there a way to override this to print always.?

Comment: window.print is pretty basic with no parameter , i guess it is not possible to reset the setting through browser

Comment: Is there any other way, I mean other than window.print() that you might be aware of? @SagarBhattacharya

Comment: the print selection and saving is done by chrome and it is not something by webpages, although their are couple of js plugin print option but i have not seen any option for destination change

Comment: only js will not be enough to do this